# IllegalArgumentException on Calendar.getTime() when lenient is false

Tags: java, calendar

In the following code I get a IllegalArgumentException but I can not understand why:

```
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.clear();
    date.setLenient(false);
    date.set(2017, 2, 26, 2, 23);
    date.getTime();//here is the Exception thrown
```

Exception Stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2829)
at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
at java.util.Calendar.getTime(Calendar.java:1755)
at WildDog.main(WildDog.java:13)
```

Any ideas?

More details after first response:
Timezone is CEST
Java is 1.8.0_102 (the problem is also on IBM 1.6_x)

Comment: It seems very likely this will depend on your system default time zone - what is it?

Comment: Please provide more info.

Comment: downvoters justify yourself

Comment: @JigarJoshi I did. It seems like another question asking for people to fix it without trying anything.

Comment: I am not given negative vote but date.getTime() is deprecated.

Comment: That code does not throw an exception when I run it in Java 1.8.0_121.  What version of Java are you using?

Comment: java.util.Calendar#getTime is as far I can read not deprecated

Comment: @johncliffe I tryed many differet variants, they are all working, just this parameters are problematic. What didi you try befor you voted down?

Comment: @JigarJoshi’s answer is correct:  that time simply does not exist in your timezone on that date.  However, if you remove `date.setLenient(false)`, the Calendar will figure out the right thing to do, and will not throw an exception.

Comment: @VGR I tested it now also with 1.8.0_121 (64 bit Windows 10). Same problem: what is your timezone?

Comment: My timezone is EDT, but I added `date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));` after the call to date.clear() in order to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time simply doesn't exist for the given timezone. Most of the [european countries](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2017.html) goes through DST shift during this time. Find out your timezone as @JonSkeet suggested and validate it. Yours is probably CET --> CEST

Comment: Default timezone is CEST, so this will not help.

Comment: `this will not help` - elaborate

Comment: setting date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CEST")) and no exception is thrown:
Thank also to @VGR